# Laravel 4 automatically create relationships in BaseModel - using "with"-array or scopes or what?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eager-loading

I have successfully created a few relations in a Model. This is the user-model

```
<?php 
  class User extends BaseModel{ 
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function group(){
        return $this -> belongsTo('UserGroup');
    }

    ...
  } 
?>
```

and this is the UserGroup-model (UserGroup.php)

```
<?php class UserGroup extends BaseModel{ ... } ?>
```

Every user can be in one group (the database-column is called 'group_id' in the users-table). If I want to do eager loading on this relation, it works perfectly fine, also for other models.

The **problem** is that I have a few models that have a lot of foreign keys and I don't want to create all relations manually. I want a function in the BaseModel that creates all those relations automatically, like

```
public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Group');
}
```

based on an array that I would provide in each model, looking like this

```
protected $foreignKeys = array(array('key' => 'group', 'model' => 'UserGroup'), ...);
```

I have read that there is an array called 'with' that you can use, but it did not work for me. Somewhere else I read I should work with query scopes but I have no idea how that could help me.

Thanks for reading and your support!

Best regards, Marcel

Comment: Ardent provides something like you'd like https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent/blob/master/src/LaravelBook/Ardent/Ardent.php#L347-L350, but I would not necessarily suggest this approach. Maybe simply create more (abstract?) models that you'd extend? And to answer your concerns - neither scopes nor `with` does what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already tried to work with the magic __call() method but then got an error that says, first() is not a defined in the Eloquent- class or so. I will try again with Ardents version and tell you if it worked, tomorrow. How would you do it with (abstract?) Models?

Comment: Hey @deczo, I read through Ardents class and it looks pretty much like what I want to have. All the validation stuff is nice, too. Why would you NOT suggest that approach? And how would you do it with models that would be extended? Thanks!

Comment: First off, I don't use Ardent because I find it not very flexible, when you need more than just base features of the Eloqeunt. To answer your question, provide some example models that you need with common relations.

Comment: For example, I could have a `FlightData`-model with following fields: `id, origin_airport, destination_airport, date, ...` and a lot of other fields, that actually are foreign keys, just as origin_airport and destination_airport are foreign keys for the `Airport`-model. I don't wanna create 15 functions that declare the relationship between the models, but simply have on array for that.

Comment: OK, that's not what I thought of. You might find Ardent-like solution better for your situation in the end. Having all the relations in an array presents more advantages to defining them as methods - you can search through those arrays if you need etc. So probably this is the way to go for you.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I'll see if I can get it working with my system. You may post that Artend-class as an Answer, so that I can vote it/you up and make it easier to see for other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ardent provides something like you'd want to implement: https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent/blob/master/src/LaravelBook/Ardent/Ardent.php#L347-L350.

As per comments:

You might find Ardent-like solution better for your situation in the end. Having all the relations in an array presents more advantages to defining them as methods - you can search through those arrays if you need etc. So probably this is the way to go for you